# Request package: response.body is not JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am using nodejs `request` module to fetch data from stackexchange api. However, I do not understand the body of the response

```
��V�n�6������$_��Ң�C��MQc�Ԓ���wHɉs�.l��s�>��㆕ڋ�
<C2��ݓ-�T��x]OȄ���T���Y�Z��2Cs�{ד;��<Ū�å��Ѭ�՚�O�x����i��+��x:��0�d$��ʬ1(��z]�R2�[�d�xnL��0��� %����T�a���f��hM�wV��Z�߭���($�z   �UA�+AJ�w�P;'�BY���L�6�n䖩��;����֏��X?��"B�'�Q5�z[�v+*ka0�(B݉�ޠ�i�)�1D�D���o�ٯ�&��d:FgPNsA}E�`:�
1H?j���Fy4O�h��;'�O����#2�H�=`Z)|Rq��J�o+�_�����I��~�d�[TI��pSظ�}��y�H8����-4
    <p���@�X�{�Y�d�4�jq��Z;����K�����}��:pu���NGt��ԟDӉ%l��M��8�&4������#d*� �Eʔbj�-, �u��
IpE��!Y�� `;�5��yX-�b)N&S)0�6�-���f��Q��8��f"i�+m�6.�M�sr�B�ST�x��y�6���l�3����
        <a[48�Mp@��(���b�'���RA�D�m���n\4.8�.��.���v5jjU���Y��25S�-�]���z�T��'�:�޲�d&�I[��7pv�:��Ф(�3���$g$�1��׮z`�0��=�+���5px��x����r��u�-�������V�}ڼ����,8L��o�%�ږ��wc�#mM��&v�N|���Z�q�pZ?J������K[���Rd��BfX/�O�#ֿ���˷
��3T�mGa�`۴�7�ƕ"[���T�}�����v_�T�@��A����g}����ӌN�]��K�,$΁gJ<��z?���ђ
k��Q�a  ����$V66�g�? �H�����1��5�c�Xi���0[i��܍�
�̞Ϝl�*��8d�����C����R0�i3��dfI�b�k]��^he�QX3�Ҏ ;�5/���X�r(��7Z�A.���tR�9D*�F�ű���V�w�o.�ɪt))4�_ҐUI<��ӻb%���'�d|��3���
```

I want the body to be in JSON format.

I tried using `JSON.parse(body)` but it throws this error

> undefined:1
>   � ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

Here is the code on my nodeJS app

```js
var questionId = req.params.id
request.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+questionId+'?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-wwYGT',
    {json:true}, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) res.status(500).json(error)
        else{
            res.status(200).send(body)
        }
    })
```

Comment: This is all of your code?  I bet you're getting gzip or deflate transfer encoding.

Comment: @Brad yup, that is all my code. How do I know if I'm getting gzip?

Comment: It's only the body of the response that has these weird characters! the rest of the response object is normal JSON.

Comment: What's the full request URI?

Comment: @Brad `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+questionId+'?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-wwYGT`

Comment: I can read your code, but what I can't do is mind-read the question ID.  :-)

Comment: @Brad something like `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/53684484?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow`

Comment: @Brad I think as you said, it has something to do with gzip according to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888647/json-url-from-stackexchange-api-returning-jibberish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange is requiring gzip.  The request module isn't requesting it by default, so it assumes that it doesn't need to decode it.

Enable gzip on the request:

```
const request = require('request');

request.get(
  {
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/53684484?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-wwYGT',
    json:true,
    gzip: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log({error, response, body});

  }
);
```

https://repl.it/repls/AppropriateSarcasticFilesize

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `request` is the [npm `request` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), the `get` method allows only two parameters (URL or options with URL, and callback) while you are passing URL and options separately.

For example:

```js
request.get({
  uri: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+questionId+'?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-wwYGT',
  json: true,
},(error, response, body) => {
  // ... callback here
});
```

Comment: this does not work. here is online demonstration: https://repl.it/@programom/fetchStackExchange